# Не работает проект Чат

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, firebase

Я еще новичок в этом деле, у меня такая проблемка, сделал навигационное меню снизу и в один из фрагментов я сделал чат с Firebase, написав код у меня ничего не получилось, т.е сообщения не отправляются в БД и вообще не видно их, код маленький и если что-то нужно могу предоставить. Попробовал бы сам решить, но логи молчат, нажимаю на кнопки и ничего. Делал по видео, если кому нужно вот: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gFtajvZajrg&list=PL0lO_mIqDDFUXOmQ5c6hurb2Nqvc1uCxe&index=4

```
public static int SIGN_IN_CODE = 1;
    FrameLayout fragment_messages;
    FirebaseListAdapter<Messages> adapter;
    FloatingActionButton sendBtn;

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_CODE) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Snackbar.make(fragment_messages, R.string.frame_message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                displayAllMessages();
            }
            else {
                Snackbar.make(fragment_messages, R.string.frame_message_error, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                requireActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    public void onCreateView(View view) {
        fragment_messages = view.findViewById(R.id.root_frame);
        sendBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText textField = v.findViewById(R.id.messageField);
                if(textField.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    return;

                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue (
                        new Messages(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),
                                textField.getText().toString()
                        )
                );
                textField.setText("");
            }
        });


        // Пользователь еще не авторизован
        if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null)
            startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(), SIGN_IN_CODE);
        else {
            Snackbar.make(fragment_messages, R.string.frame_message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            displayAllMessages();
        }

    }

    private void displayAllMessages() {
        View view = null;
        assert false;
        ListView listOfMessages = view.findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

        FirebaseListOptions<Messages> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Messages>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(), Messages.class)
                .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Messages>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(@NonNull View v, @NonNull Messages model, int position) {
                TextView mess_user, mess_time, mess_text;
                mess_user = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                mess_time = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
                mess_text = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);

                mess_user.setText(model.getUserName());
                mess_time.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-mm-yyyy HH:mm:ss", model.getMessageTime()));
                mess_text.setText(model.getTextMessage());
            }
        };

        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Откладка
[image: Откладка приложения]

Код входа в приложение

```
                .addOnSuccessListener(authResult -> {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivityEntrance.this, MainActivityHomePage.class));
                    finish();
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.root_element), getString(R.string.Authorisation_error) + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

Comment: посмотрите под отладкой формируется ли сообщения и уходит ли что-то в firebase, так же на видео приведена настройка бд чтобы поддерживать чат - вы все сделали так же? допускаю что у вас может быть проблема на стороне firebase

Comment: @Andrew да все сделал, как на видео, только переформировал это в fragment, а не в активити. Я еще не силен в откладке, но я предоставил скриншот в обсуждение. Если вам не сложно посмотрите пожалуйста. А так же я удалил регистрацию пользователя, т.к у меня она есть.

Comment: вот есть пример как работать с отладкой https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nBaL78HC0ls, и как вы определяете что у вас работает авторизация? может у вас не проходит auth и поэтому до бд вы не доходите

Comment: @Andrew благодарю за видеоматериал, сейчас буду изучать. А насчет авторизации, авторизация и регистрации у меня до фграгментов, т.е начальная страница, в бд все поступает из авторизации

Comment: @Andrew тут с кодом наверное проблема... даже не знаю, попробую сейчас новый проект создать и там проверить работоспособность кода, так как возможно я не правильно преобразовал код с активити на фрагмент, там же не все поддерживается как надл

Comment: Хм... А как вы в текущем фрагменте понимаете что авторизовались? Суть на видеоролике который вы смотрели в том что все в пределах одного класса сделано, и посему после авторизации юзер становится активным, как вы это поддерживаете в своей архитектуре?

Comment: В общем создал новый чистый проект без фрагментов, там все работает как по видео, что доказывает что я тупой :(, извиняюсь не совсем понял, но я оставил код сверху который отвечает за проверку есть ли такой пользователь в FIrebase и при успешном выполнение открывает дальше, т.е экран где храниться фрагменты.

Comment: вам нужно понять каким образом сохранить авторизацию за пределам одного класса и расшарить это состояние на ваши фрагменты

Comment: @Andrew т.е мне сделать так чтобы каждый раз пользователь не вводил данные? чтобы аккаунт остался активным до момента как он сам не выйдет, правильно ли я вас понял? Заранее извиняюсь

Comment: @Andrew я тут подумал, а что если проверку авторизован ли пользователь перенести в MainActivity который соединяет все Фрагменты?

Comment: ну можно, но как вы в фрагменте поймете что пользователь авторизован или нет? изначально вопрос простой - зачем вам делить все на фрагменты?

Comment: @Andrew это проект для дипломной работы, у меня кроме чата там будет чата, расписание, оценки и т.п, для этого я спроектировал навигационную панель. А насчет вашего вопроса, я еще думаю и читаю про это и как это сделать